# I am unable to get my Dart model working properly. I am able when its a list, but this model works with a api endpoint that gives back a single device

Tags: dart, model, endpoint

I am having issues with my model in dart. Here is my code:

```
class Device {
  Map<String, dynamic> _device = {};
  Map<String, dynamic> get device => _device;

  Device({required device}) {
    this._device = device;
  }

  Device.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _device = (json['device'] != null
        ? new Device.fromJson(json['device'])
        : null) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  }
}
```

[image: image of error]

Comment: In case of `json['device'] != null` being false, you are returning `null` in your expression. You are then trying to typecast this `null` into `Map<String, dynamic>` which fails because `Map<String, dynamic>` is a non-nullable type. If you want to allow `null` as a value, you need to use `Map<String, dynamic>?` as the type (note the `?` at the end).

Comment: Also I am rather confused about what you want to do in your code. It looks like you are trying to call the `Device.fromJson` constructor from the `Device.fromJson` constructor? Also, the result of calling the constructor is a `Device` instance but you are then trying to typecast that into a `Map<String, dynamic>`. I wonder what you actually want to do here?

Comment: It looks that way because I didnt share the rest of the code as it wasnt completely relevant.

Comment: Ok. But I still guess that your `_device` variable are wrongly typed and you was supposed to use your own class as type instead. Especially since we want to get rid of `dynamic` as much as possible when parsing.

Comment: I put the ? at the end of the string of code and before the semicolon, however it tells me I need to add a null check to which it adds a ! and then I just get an error again anyways.  I made this model by copying my result from the api in postman and then going to https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/, pasting it in the box and having it auto generate my model for me.

Comment: Also, a tutorial that I followed had me do it this way. I am new to Dart and have no one to ask so I am limping along at best. Trust me, I am equally annoyed and frustrated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245565/discussion-between-julemand101-and-mackina).